# Cutting in a plane using an image as a mask

Tags: image, knife-tool, height-map

I would like to create **independent tortoiseshells** meshes from a boolean mask. The boolean mask would be used to cut in the plane automatically.

The method I am using at the moment is to use the cut knife and cut through a plane by hand. I am following the curves of the reference image, here a crocodile skin, to finally obtain independent tortoiseshells meshes.

[image]

I am pretty sure it should be possible to use a boolean image to directly cut through the plane with it but I didn't find anything online to help me. Here is an example of a boolean version of the crocodile skin.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: it happens often that people ask here for x to achieve y. But there might be quicker and faster ways to do that. So maybe you can tell us a bit more of your end goal? So maybe you could be surprised be the answers... ;)

Comment: @Chris , it is for 3d printing. The end result should be separated tortoiseshells that could be manipulated **like a puzzle** :) (I hope it helps)

Comment: ah, that helps a lot! because what came up to my mind instead of cutting the shapes...i would generate them with geometry nodes ...or other tools.

Comment: Do you know any geometry node tool using an image as reference to perform action?

Comment: unfortunately no...but i think now others know what you wanna do and hopefully they will help ;)

Comment: Do you need the pieces to fit tightly like a jigsaw, or are the gaps as shown acceptable?

Comment: ( https://imgur.com/a/1VId9B3 )

Comment: WoW Robin. That looks clean! It’s exactly what I’d need. The gaps are totally acceptable

Comment: Can you deliver your secrets to someone with immense gratitude?

Comment: @RobinBetts, I don't want to be heavy :( but are you gonna deliver me your secrets, I have put my project on hold :p

Comment: @AndrewKaram  Very sorry, have had to be away. Will put together an answer

Answer (score 1):

This could be a route..

First resolve your pattern to a bitmap. That could be via an external paint-package, or by picking up one of those readily available on the internet. If it's a must to take it from your personal reference, then if you provide it, we could have a go, but it's not strictly a Blender problem.

Once a bitmap, it can be <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> added to your scene as a Reference Image (That's an Image Empty).....

[image]

Once an Empty, 'Trace Image to Grease Pencil' is available in the Header > Object menu. Trace.

Then the Grease pencil can be converted to a curve. For some reason, on my machine, the curve refuses to fill, in its native Data tab >  Curve > Fill settings. But a little Geometry Nodes modifier, with just one *Fill Curve* node, did the trick. At this point, you might want to Curve > Clean Up > Decimate the curve in Edit Mode, to get rid of excess vertices.

If you've gone down that road, the object can now be Converted > to Mesh. and you're more or less there:

[image]